# What is a linear pooling layer?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

1. What is a linear pooling layer?
2. What can be the maximum size of a linear pooling kernel?
3. Do you use dense layers after linear layers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Same as a normal pooling layer, but along one dimension. I.e., instead of selecting max response from a `n x n` window, select from `1 x n`. Perhaps it makes sense mostly if the previous output is one-dimensional.
2. Size of the previous output along the desired dimension
3. Nothing prevents you from doing so. Just do whatever makes sense.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, where can I find an example implementation on a dummy dataset? I can't imagine how would a dense layer work on an already linear layer.

Comment: @LeonRai there is no need to implement, Keras already has it as `MaxPooling1D`

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I mean like a tutorial where I can see how it works on a dummy dataset.